# Xamarin for Android: Automatically taking photos -- something similar to UWP's MediaCapture functionality

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

A wrote a robotics app using UWP a few years ago, which automatically takes photos. I want to convert it to an Android (and possibly iOS) app with Xamarin, but I noticed that Xamarin's MediaPicker is a far cry from UWP's MediaCapture object. With MediaCapture I could have my app take several pictures completely on its own, without the user having to click on any buttons, with this code:

```
MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaSettings);
Low​Lag​Photo​Capture photoCapture = await mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagPhotoCaptureAsync(imageProperties);
CapturedPhoto photo = await photoCapture.CaptureAsync();
CapturedFrame frame = photo.Frame;
SoftwareBitmap SWBitmap = frame.SoftwareBitmap;
```

Is there a way to do the same in Xamarin?

Comment: Short story, yes. Long story, you will probably have to write this logic yourself. MediaPicker from whatever library is not for the use case you are trying to apply it to. You will need to get your hands dirty with the AndroidX Camera2 and do this yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But I am confined to the Visual Studio 2019/Xamarin environment, I am not doing it directly with Android SDK.

Comment: @O.T.Vinta The full Android SDK is exposed via `Xamarin.Android` and available to you within the VS environment

Comment: Thanks. NuGet search yields quite a few packages: xamarin.android.support.compat, xamarin.android.support.annotations, xamarin.android.support.core.utils, etc. Do you happen to know which ones I need? Thanks again.

Comment: Why are you searching for nuget packages?  The necessary camera APIs should be available in the Android project for you to use.  Here is a sample app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android50-camera2basic/.  There are plenty of other samples, tutorials and documentation available

Comment: Had you tried to pass the data and save it directly after calling the [takephoto method](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/take-photo)?

Comment: These code samples have these: using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Hardware.Camera2;
using Android.Graphics;  Those are not available to my project.

Comment: It seems there is no nuget package for xamarin.android to do this, so you need to use the API to call the camera and take photo by yourself like Cheesebaron said.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT -- can you give me an example of such an API function?

Comment: The api which calls the camera you had mentioned above, but why you say they are not available to your project.